# Law about adult video websites retaining actors' PII

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, criminal-law, civil-law, common-law

Pretend there is a British person in the United Kingdom (England & Wales jurisdiction), that for some legally justifiable reason needs to obtain the name (and other information) of a female adult video actress in the United States of America. The video in question is legal (all parties are 18 years or older) and is available on a both well known and popular adult video website.

Are there laws in the United States which obligate adult video websites to retain personal information (such as first and second names) of the actors/actresses in the videos uploaded on their website? If so, could someone please provide them?

I am unsure as to whether it would be a Federal, State, or other law as I am not familiar with the United States legal system. To make an educated guess, I assume it would be Federal since it concerns somebody from outside the US making a request, but I might be wrong.

**EDIT:**
As per **Trish** in the comments, if this is something applicable to the film producers rather than the adult video website (or whatever) just inform me accordingly.

Comment: Careful: Most hosts of adult material actually host copyright infringing material, as in pirated copy of material sold or streamed elsewhere. In any way, in most cases, actors in adult films act under a "pen name". Only the film company knows their proper names in many cases.

Comment: @Trish I appreciate the input, and I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: *"for some legally justifiable reason needs to obtain the name (and other information)"* - I wonder what this reason could possibly be. Perhaps you are the executor of an eccentric person's last will and testament, which bestows their worldly possessions to an adult film actress of uncertain identity? Perhaps you recognise them as your long lost identical twin, or they are depicted in the video wearing a unique piece of jewellery stolen from your ancestors? If it's not something extraordinary like that, then I would strongly recommend against trying to invade this person's privacy.

Comment: @kaya3 I doubt recognising them as a long lost identical twin would constitute a legitimate reason for requesting the PII. It'd be a reason to reach out to the actor through usual informal methods (e.g. twitter), but if I ran such a website and had the PII I certainly wouldn't provide it to someone just because they claimed to be a long lost relative (even an identical twin)

Comment: Just to put it more bluntly than @kaya3's delicate comment: Notwithstanding the text saying "some legally justifiable reason", **this type of question overwhelmingly suggests that somebody wants to stalk, either in person or digitally, a performer. Legal or otherwise, that is a hostile and unpleasant thing to do** (and I write for future readers/answerers of the question who may have reached it from Google, not specifically the OP).

Comment: In the examples above, I would just ask the website owner to contact them on my behalf without providing me with their contact details, and failing that I would use Twitter etc... as suggested. In my case, perhaps a girl made a false allegation of being rapped for her virginity, yet two years prior she was having a lot of sex in adult movies proving she is not a virgin and is relevant evidence for a court case? This is only an example, my question is just out of academic interest. I appreciate the stalking comments, but any website should know not to hand out PII without a warrant etc...

Comment: The rape-allegation example lacks hand and foot: if someone is alleged to have raped someone, they can file discovery against the witness to impeach it, because the witness is already on the list of witnesses. Getting the PII from the website would not be needed at all. Instead, the defendant's attorney can ask "Have you worked in the adult entertainment industry? Is this you on the video?" - which by the way will be seen as **very poor taste** by many juries - alleging that an actor can't be raped is absolutely rock bottom behavior for an attorney and could get disciplinary action rolling.

Comment: @Trish "file discovery against the witness to impeach it" sounds very American, for a British person living in London... Additionally, you do realise sometimes people have similar faces, the whole reason I asked this question was to be more certain. Also, irrespective of what the jury think, how can a girl be raped for her VIRGINITY when she had vaginal sex two years prior in a porn video?

Answer (score 21):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

> Are there laws in the United States which obligate adult video
> websites to retain personal information (such as first and second
> names) of the actors/actresses in the videos uploaded on their
> website? If so, could someone please provide them?

In the U.S. producers of adult material are required to keep information about the age of their performers pursuant to [18 U.S. Code § 2257](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2257) and [18 U.S. Code § 2257A](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2257A) which is part of "The Child Protection and Obscenity Enforcement Act of 1988", and [28 C.F.R. 75](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-28/chapter-I/part-75) which contains regulations adopted related to that Code section. *See also* [U.S. Justice Department commentary](https://www.justice.gov/criminal-ceos/18-usc-2257-2257a-certifications) on its website. You can read the full text at the links. The information must be retained for seven years after they are created or last amended, unless the business goes out of business less than two years after the records are created or last amended, in which case the records must be maintained for five years after the business ceases to operate.

They key language of  Section 2257 states:

> (a)Whoever produces any book, magazine, periodical, film, videotape,
> digital image, digitally- or computer-manipulated image of an actual
> human being, picture, or other matter which—
>
> (1)contains one or more visual depictions made after November 1, 1990
> of actual sexually explicit conduct; and
>
> (2)is produced in whole or in part with materials which have been
> mailed or shipped in interstate or foreign commerce, or is shipped or
> transported or is intended for shipment or transportation in
> interstate or foreign commerce;
>
> shall create and maintain individually identifiable records pertaining
> to every performer portrayed in such a visual depiction.
>
> (b)Any person to whom subsection (a) applies shall, with respect to
> every performer portrayed in a visual depiction of actual sexually
> explicit conduct—
>
> (1)ascertain, by examination of an identification document containing
> such information, the performer’s name and date of birth, and require
> the performer to provide such other indicia of his or her identity as
> may be prescribed by regulations;
>
> (2)ascertain any name, other than the performer’s present and correct
> name, ever used by the performer including maiden name, alias,
> nickname, stage, or professional name; and
>
> (3)record in the records required by subsection (a) the information
> required by paragraphs (1) and (2) of this subsection and such other
> identifying information as may be prescribed by regulation.

Section 2257A extends this requirement to simulated sexual content.

The regulations spell out the details requirements more specifically with more precise definitions.

Much of this information may only be disclosed to specified individuals and is not necessarily available to members of the general public in the absence of an investigation authorized by the U.S. Attorney General.

But access to these records is not governed by these statutes and regulations. An objection to a subpoena and request for a protective order under Federal Rule of Civil Procedure 45 (and related rules) or the equivalent state court rule would be the usual process for litigating that point. Whether the reason asserted is really justifiable would be a question for other law (usually under the law of California where most adult material in the U.S. is produced).

Comment: California also has unusually strong privacy laws restricting what companies can store or give out, so it would be particularly hard to get information from a Californian company without a strong reason to do so.

Comment: Note that some courts have suggested that § 2257 may be unconstitutional in some circumstances - see https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wikilegal/Age_Record_Requirement#Constitutionality

Comment: @Smitop The cases cited are quite old and a finding of unconstitutionality hasn't come dow  in the meantime.

Comment: Would it be worth mentioning that in many cases, the website hosting the material is not the "producer" of the material with a record keeping obligation?

Comment: @AldusBumblebore I am not familiar at that level of detail with how the online pornography industry is organized from an economic perspective. I know where the statutes are located and what they say, but not how things are usually done in the industry.

Comment: @ohwilleke Lol to that. The fact is, quite a few of the largest porn sites are hosting user-uploaded content, similar to YouTube. I would expect them to have zero regulatory records since they produce zero material. Even the biggest porn producers with their own sites use these YouTube-like sites to promote their own sites. Or at least that's what a friend told me....

Comment: @AldusBumblebore The uploading user is the *producer* for the law, and they have to have documentation about the age of all actors. And most of the uploaded content on such sites is ripped from actual porn and re-cut, making it copyright infringement anyway.

Comment: @Trish Yes, all very true, and that brings us full circle now to my original comment.

Comment: @AldusBumblebore "I would expect them to have zero regulatory records since they produce zero material": I believe they incur criminal liability for certain material, so I imagine that they keep records showing that they have reason to believe that the uploaders are 18 years old or older, even if the justification for those records isn't 18 USC 2257 when the hosting site does not meet the definition of "producer" under that section.

Comment: @phoog "I believe they incur criminal liability for certain material..." Oh yes I'm sure you are correct here. "...so I imagine that they keep records..." On this I am not so sure. Citation required, I think! Since such sites may not be American or EU, mileage may vary.